# How to go from the more intuitive Present Value expression to the more general and concise one?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

I am studying finance and I come across some formulas that I've been trying to get some intuition on. Here we have an equality of (simplified and applied to 3 periods without the Cash flow part) PV expressions:

$$\dfrac{1}{1+x}+\dfrac{1}{\left( 1+x\right) ^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{\left( 1+x\right) ^{3}}=\dfrac{1}{x}\left( 1-\dfrac{1}{\left( 1+x\right) ^{3}}\right)$$

I know that they are equal, but after several hours trying to go from the left expression to the right one I have not managed to do it.

Can someone walk me through (or point to) the steps needed to arrive at the right expression?

Answer (score 0):

If you let $r=\frac1{1+x}$, the LHS is $r+r^2+r^3$.

Notice that $1-r=1-\frac1{1+x}=\frac{x}{1+x}=rx$.

Hence the right hand side should be $$r\cdot \frac{1-r^3}{1-r}=r\cdot \frac{1-r^3}{rx}=\frac{1-r^3}{x}$$

Comment: I confess that I am a bit confused. If we let r = 1/(1+x), shouldn't the LHS be r+r^2+r^3? We could then factor out an r and have r(1+r^+r^2) but still, I don't understand the pertinence of the following simplifications on the RHS since that doesn't help me understanding how one goes from the LHS to the RHS without previously knowing the latter.

Comment: thanks, I made a mistake earlier. I used the formula from [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)